# How to share as image from the Wikipedia App?

Tags: applications

The [Wikipedia app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikipedia) supposedly allows sharing selected text as an image, [as seen on diff.wikipedia.org](https://diff.wikimedia.org/2015/04/02/share-a-fact-with-friends-on-android-app).

At the moment, at least on my phone (Nokia 7.2 TA-1196, Android 10), only “standard sharing” is available, which shares plain text.

Does the feature still exist? How can one share as image?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it on Wikipedia app (2.7.5033+2020-08-04) on a Samsung S9 running Android 10. And I was not able to have text over image via the share button as described. That feature was from 2015 and based on the comments in your linked post, they was some concern about image rights issues.

Regardless, I was able tap on an article image for normal sharing.